# Add some HTML element when script src is blocked

Tags: javascript

I'm curious if it's possible to create some HTML element, when some script src is blocked by browser (f.e. because of incognito mode). Consider the following code, how it could be modified to achieve it?

```js
(function() {
  var w = window;
  var ic = w.Intercom;
  if (typeof ic === "function") {
    ic('reattach_activator');
    ic('update', intercomSettings);
  } else {
    var d = document;
    var i = function() {
      i.c(arguments)
    };
    i.q = [];
    i.c = function(args) {
      i.q.push(args)
    };
    w.Intercom = i;

    function l() {
      var s = d.createElement('script');
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.async = true;
      s.src = 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/viov7xor';
      var x = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    }
    if (w.attachEvent) {
      w.attachEvent('onload', l);
    } else {
      w.addEventListener('load', l, false);
    }
  }
})()
```

Comment: So, you want to check if a file is loaded in the browser?

Comment: Why would incognito mode block a script?

Comment: @mplungjan ok, so firefox tracking protection for example :)

Comment: Do you control the potentially-blocked scripts. Can you add some lines to the end of those scripts?

Comment: @VladimirM which scripts? I'm not able to modify intercom scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added this line of code in `l` function of the above code ... now it creates div when some error with intercom script occurs.

```
s.onerror=()=>{var ierr=d.createElement('div');ierr.id='intercom-error';d.body.appendChild(ierr)};
```